# opengl displaying white box instead of texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glfw, soil

I have a texture which I am displaying using the following:

```
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
        glGenTextures(1, tex);
    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex);
        glBegin (GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f (tx, ty);
        glVertex2f (sx, sy);
        glTexCoord2f (tw, ty);
        glVertex2f (sx + sxmax, sy);
        glTexCoord2f (tw, th);
         glVertex2f (sx + sxmax, sy + symax);
        glTexCoord2f (tx, th);
       glVertex2f (sx, sy + symax);
        glEnd();
        glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDisable (GL_BLEND);
```

I am loading the texture using the following:

```
    GLuint GetTexture(string Filename)
    {
        GLuint tex_ID;

        tex_ID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
                     Filename.c_str(),
                     SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                     SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
                     SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO
                     | SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS
                     | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA
                     | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
                     | SOIL_FLAG_DDS_LOAD_DIRECT
                     | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
                 );

        if( tex_ID > 0 )
        {

            glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ID );

            return tex_ID;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Texture failed to load"<<SOIL_last_result()<<Filename<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

and passing it by reference to a class

When I run a check to see if the texture loaded properly:

```
if(tex==0)
```

it is. Additionally whenever i run `glColor3f();` with some values nothing is displayed ont the screen.
what have I done wrong?

I am using glfw and SOIL to load/display the textures.

Comment: try doing small steps: first load a texture and try to render it (without blening enabled), then add blending. load texture using this flags: SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y (one flag only, just to test). If you have working texture then try adding blending...

Comment: Do you ever re-`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` after the first frame?

Comment: What's the type of `tex` in the first code block?

Comment: Yes i did reenable gl_texture_2d, just missed it in the copy pasting, tex is declared as follows: GLuint * tex;

Comment: removing blending appears to make no difference

Comment: You are aware that having a non-zero value of tex does not actually indicate whether it's "loaded properly" or not? The only thing this indicates is that OpenGL generated an object handle (name) for you, the handle does not necessarily have a data store associated with it. In fact, in older implementations, OpenGL does not even know what a generated handle is supposed to represent until you actually call `glTexImage2D (...)` or try to bind it -- you could actually call `glGenTextures (...)` and then use that handle as a VBO if you wanted :P

Answer (score 3):

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
glGenTextures(1, tex);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I hope tex didn't have anything important in it...
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex);
glBegin (GL_QUADS);
....
```

You're generating an entirely new *empty* texture *every frame*.  Which also happens to be [incomplete](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture).

Generate a texture *once* and use that.