# opengl generating a white box instead of a texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glfw, soil

I have the following code which I am using to render a texture:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex);
    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f (sx, sy);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.1);
    glVertex2f (sx + sxmax, sy);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f (sx + sxmax, sy + symax);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f (sx, sy + symax);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable( GL_BLEND );
    glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glPopAttrib();
```

Before that code is run I do the following:
glGenTextures (1, tex);
However it simply generates a white box on the screen.
tex is of type GLuint and is created using the following:

```
GLuint GetTexture (string Filename) {
    GLuint tex_ID;
    tex_ID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture (
                 Filename.c_str(),
                 SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                 SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
                 SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO
                 | SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS
                 | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA
                 | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
                 | SOIL_FLAG_DDS_LOAD_DIRECT
                 | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
             );

    if ( tex_ID > 0 ) {
        glEnable ( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ID );
        return tex_ID;
    } else {
        cout << "Texture failed to load" << SOIL_last_result() << Filename << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am using soil to generate the texture and GLFW to display it, this is all in C++. What have I done wrong?

running glgeterror returns error code 1281

Comment: The effect of the "white" texture, is usually because `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` isn't called, thereby currently disabled at the point trying to render using a texture.

Comment: You have a few other errors in your code, in addition. For example, you're setting the `glClearColor()`, but you're not ever clearing the color buffer, so it has no effect. You need to call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`. Then you set the texture parameter after you've used the texture. Also, can you verify that the texture actually got read properly? It could be all white. Does `glGetError()` return any error information?

Comment: glgeterror returns error 1281

Comment: I do clear the buffer but later in code that I did not believe was relevent

Comment: Why are you generating a texture ID and then asking SOIL to generate another using `SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [opengl displaying white box instead of texture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495411/opengl-displaying-white-box-instead-of-texture)